# Syntax error when adding SSH key in GitLab CI

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, build-script

Reference: https://gitlab.ida.liu.se/help/ci/ssh_keys/README.md

The following script has problems. Even though I changed the last symbol from ` to ' , **the question is how to fix the error as shown below**:

$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY") /bin/sh: eval: line 24: syntax error: unexpected "("

```
before_script:
  # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

  # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
  # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
  # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
  # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried many times, the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` should work properly.

```
    image: gitlab/dind:latest

variables:
  COMPOSE: docker-compose

before_script:
  # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

  # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
  # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
  # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
  # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh

  - ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts -o ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  - '[[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

# Add a job called 'build' -> to run your builds
# TODO: Build the image in remote docker registry 
build-dev:
  stage: build 
  script:
    - sh scripts/install-dev.sh
    - $COMPOSE build
  only:
    - dev 

build-master:
  stage: build 
  script:
    - sh scripts/install.sh
    - $COMPOSE build
  only:
    - master
```

I have also opened an issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1491).

Answer (score 4):

To make it work I had to replace:

```sh
ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

with:

```sh
printenv SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | ssh-add -
```